# Issues translating Postman Collection to OpenApi converter to Golang program

Tags: go, post, openapi

For my project, I wanted to write some code that would allow me to fetch a postman collection, given the collection ID, then translate that collection to an OpenAPI 3 spec. I found some converter tools on Postman Public Work Spaces and tried integrating that locally in Golang, however I am having issues with the POST request that actually accesses the tool for conversion. Here's how its setup on Postman workspace.
[Postman UI to send GET request and retrieve collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkeRJ.png)

[The test script on Workspace that sends the POST script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eivN1.png)

The test script is essentially what I'm trying to implement locally in Go.

[GET Request implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyk6Y.png)

This is the Golang implementation for sending the GET request to retrieve the collection. I got it straight from the workspaces and it works correctly.

[POST Request implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba5ox.png)

This is how I have translated the POST request in Go. Currently I'm getting bad request errors, which are due to the body object I'm passing in this request. I tried formatting the body object the same as they did in the Postman Workspace script, but I'm not sure why its causing a bad request error.

Comment: don't share text as screenshots.  It's imperative that we get all text as pasted text.